# will_paginate starts next page count from 1 with indexing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an indexed page of posts and it goes like:

```
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
   //do some rendering
<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

While in my controller i have the following:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
end
```

The first page numbering counts up to 15 but when i proceed to page two the index count goes back to 1. I want it to proceed from 15 onwards. Thankx

Comment: What `debug @posts` shows? first 15 or next 15? If next 15 - then you can try `@posts.to_a.each_with_index`

Comment: let me try this out and see

Comment: @Mik_Die it failed. Still trying to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Had to browse through the will_paginate code to come up with a solution. In recipe model i added this method.

```
def offset(page)
    per_page = 15
    @off_set = WillPaginate::PageNumber(page).to_offset(per_page).to_i
end
```

While in my controller i added:

```
def index
     @page = params[:page]
end
```

Finally in my view i added this:

```
<%= index + recipe.offset(@page) + 1 %>
```