# Rails will_paginate: how to keep consistent array index across pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, will-paginate

I'm using the Rails `will_paginate` gem with Rails 3.2. I have about 750 movies in my database, and I'm putting them in a table in my view. Here's the haml:

```
%h1 Listing movies
%table.table.table-striped
  %tr
    %th No.
    %th Name
    %th Rating
    %th
  - @movies.each_with_index do |movie, index|
    %tr
      %td= (index + 1) 
      %td= link_to movie.name, edit_movie_path(movie)
      %td= movie.rating
      %td= link_to 'Delete', movie, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

I've got `default_scope order: 'name ASC'` in my `movie.rb` model to sort them alphabetically, and the `each_with_index` gives me the ability to have a consistent numerical list of them in the table.

The problem is, now that I'm using pagination, the `index` of the movie array starts over at every page, so it always just says 1-10.

The question is, how can I make page 1 give say 1-10, then say 11-20 on page 2, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you may have to modify will_paginate source code to get the page index to work like you intended to (see [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740141/will-paginate-starts-next-page-count-from-1-with-indexing)).

I'll just used a session variable declared in the controller and incremented in my view to get around this.

```
session[:index] ||= 0
if params[:search]
   session[:index] = 0
end

# View
<% session[:index] = session[:index] + 1 %>
```

**[EDITED]**
An alternative solution, and thanks to @pjam comment, is to `use params[:page]` returned by will_paginate. If for example you set `:per_page => 5`, your index of current page can be calculated as follow:

```
@offset = (params[:page] - 1) * params[:per_page] + 1

# View
index + @offset
```

Comment: Just as a side note, I think using session variable would be overkill. As you have the page params available and the per_page constant defined in the model you can make a helper that give you the current offset with those 2 values

Comment: This sounds like the right track, but for some reason, `params[:per_page]` is returning nil, even though I have this in the `index` method of my controller: `@movies = Movie.search(params[:search]).paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])`

Comment: Instead of `params[:per_page]`, I tried `Movie.per_page` and that worked. Is that the best solution? If so, want to add it to your edit?

Comment: @nickcoxdotme: per_page is just a constant. You can just as well use the integral value, like 5, in the arithmetics. The variable unit is the page params.